# Rsyncing to a compressed zpool

Tags: rsync, solaris, zfs

I've been Rsyncing from an NFS mount to a local zpool that has compression enabled on it.

When I rsync, it copies every file over, not just the new/changed ones.  Is this because the file size is different on the two due to the compression on the destination?

Syntax I'm using:  rsync -vr /source/ /destination/

Comment: How many files actually change? Run rsync with the `--stats` flag to see a more detailed summary.

Comment: To see the results of the --stats flag would take over two days because the source is ~12TB.  Less than 3% of the files change per week by my estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a syntax issue.  Using the -a (archive) switch fixed it.  My initial syntax wasn't copying the "file modified date".

Answer (score 2):

The fact the file is compressed shouldn't matter with `rsync` as the reported size by `stat` internally used by `rsync` is the uncompressed one.

I suspect more a clock mismatch between the NFS server and the client. You can verify there is no copy with:

```
rsync -vr --size-only /source/ /destination/
```

Comment: Possible, but they are connected to the same internal NTP server.  After doing some searching it might be that -vr switch doesn't preserve the attributes but -va will.  Will report back after running -va twice.